# Magento 2 very slow

Tags: magento2

I am working with Magento 2.1.2.
We have 2 Magento 2 but one is very fast and other is very slow. I am in production mode and I have cache enabled.

Why it is slow?

Thanks

Comment: It also deals with CDN & htaccess http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41034465/how-to-add-leverage-browser-caching-for-cdn-in-htaccess & https://www.keycdn.com/blog/speed-up-magento/